# how to filter piped information with grep and filter all if word is found

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to pipe in to grep and if word is found I would like do disregard entire block like

```
command | grep -v nothing && echo "disregarded block" || (echo the entire block of data)
```

all that in a bash file...

Any suggestions??

Comment: Its much better you give example data and what you like to get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
buf=$(tmpfile)
command > $buf
if grep -vq "nothing" $buf; then echo 'disregarded block'; else cat $buf; fi
unlink $buf
```

Answer (score 0):

If the command doesn't output any NUL character, with GNU `grep` (as typically found on many systems built around a Linux kernel), you can do:

```
command | grep -zv nothing
```